# When running a snapshot test with Verify an exception is thrown because the verified.txt.bak file is still there

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, snapshot-testing

I'm using Verify.Xunit (version 19.11.2) in a .NET 6 xUnit test project.
Tests are running in the Rider IDE.
To do the Verify actual/expected string comparison Verify uses WinMerge.

Sometimes (more often than not) when running a test the temporary verified.txt.bak file is still there.
The test is complaining about the existence of this bak file.

```
VerifyException
Directory: C:\code\SnapshotTesting\SnapshotTesting
Delete:
  - UnitTest.CreateReport_ShouldBeAsExpected.verified.txt.bak
Equal:
  - Received: UnitTest.CreateReport_ShouldBeAsExpected.received.txt
    Verified: UnitTest.CreateReport_ShouldBeAsExpected.verified.txt

  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

I would expect that cleaning up this bak file is not my task and be sone automatically so I was wondering what could cause this issue?
After removing the bak file the test works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed in version 20.5.0 of verify